# Is it possible to direct the executed command in a script with bash?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have a script that executes a program and direct the output to a log file.

```
./a.out --option 1  > log.txt
./a.out --option 2 >> log.txt
...
```

I would like to direct the executed command lines (
"./a.out --option 1  ", "./a.out --option 1  ",...) to the same log file so that I could distinguish which output is for which command.
Is it possible? I could add "echo command" but it doesn't seem a good way to do it since I have to write the same string twice and possibly make a mistake.

It seems trivial but I could not find on Google or a similar quesition:( so please let me ask here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a function:

```
my_command() {
    { echo "Option $1"; ./a.out --option "$1"; } >> log.txt
}

my_command 1
my_command 2
```

If you want to store the whole command line, you could use a variable:

```
my_command() {
    local cmd="./a.out --option $1"
    { echo "$cmd"; $cmd; } >> log.txt
}

my_command 1
my_command 2
```

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf None of the answers in that FAQ addresses this use case.

Comment: `cmd="./a.out --option $1"`: you're putting a command in a variable. How doesn't the FAQ address this?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I said "answers in that FAQ". If you think one of the answers applies, tell me which one.

Comment: Storing commands in a variable is an anti-pattern. Here you're dealing with options of the same command. [5. I'm constructing a command based on information that is only known at run time](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I.27m_constructing_a_command_based_on_information_that_is_only_known_at_run_time) applies.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf True, we could use an array. I skipped over that section because there is no runtime dependency in this code. It's all static.

Comment: By the way, [a hyphen in a function name is unspecified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_05): A function name is a name and must fulfill the properties of the definition: [**3.231 Name** _In the shell command language, a word consisting solely of underscores, digits, and alphabetics from the portable character set. The first character of a name is not a digit._](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_231)

Comment: A compliant (and safe) way to write this: `my_command() { set -- --option "$1"; echo "./a.out $*"; ./a.out "$@"; }; { my_command 1; my_command 2; } > log.txt`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf That duplicates `./a.out`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf This is bash, though, which allows `-` in function names.

Comment: `set -- ./a.out --option "$1"; echo "$*"; "$@"` to not have to duplicate `./a.out`. Even though `-` and many more funny characters are allowed in Bash function names, it's still better to stick with compliant names—especially here, the script is so trivial that no bash-specific features are being used…

Comment: How can I do if I have multiple options not only one? --optionA 1 --optionB 2 . Can I put all the opitons(and setting) into one variable and use it?

Answer (score 0):

You can put commands in a sequence, like this:

```
( cmd1 ; cmd2 ; cmdn ) > file
```